# File-based inputs to rigid-body animations

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I would like to specify the motions of a rigid-body in a blender scene using 3-component acceleration data (or velocity, or displacement data) that I read from a file. That would allow me to record motions in the real-world, and then, later, animate them in an object in a blender scene based on the recorded motions. I see that I can animate rigid-bodes in blenders scenes with the mouse. Is there a way I can animate objects with file-based data? Do I need the game engine to accomplish this?

Comment: so basically , you have a motion capture and you want , lets say a cube , to follow the mocop?

Comment: Yes, for this application I want to use motion capture from a phone with an accelerometer. I don't know the term mocop, but I think you understand what I am trying to do. Let's say want to animate a martini shaker in blender. First I create a blender scene with a martini shaker, and ice cubes in it. I have a separate iPhone app that collects data. The user shakes their phone and I collect the data. I transfer the data from the iPhone accelerometer to my mac, as a file. Then I use the recorded data to animate my shaker in my blender scene, like the user shook their phone.

Comment: ohh i see i see , so its a transferal to blender ?

Comment: mocap means motion capture

Comment: yes, a transferal of capture motion to blender. One reason I'm interested in using data-files to move rigid-bodies in my blender scene, is so I can repeat exactly the same motions to the scene, and evaluate how different rigid-body physics settings affect the response of objects in the scene.

Comment: i see , I think you could do that by making the object you want  a child of the armature

Comment: Rigid body objects can be controlled by keyframes, so you could use python to read the file and create keyframes accordingly..